# What's missing?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, flags

**Replace the question mark with the correct flag.**

---

[image]

Comment: Realized the title could be misleading, so I removed the first part.

Comment: ROT13( Gur zvffvat zbagu va gur obk pbeerfcbaqvat gb Netragvan vf Znl (gurer arrqf gb or na Z orgjrra gur N naq W), naq gur rzoyrz va gur zvqqyr bs gur synt vf pnyyrq gur Fha bs Znl. ) Suspicious but I don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: @oAlt You're correct regarding the first part, but it's not related to the flag.

Comment: Are the letters in the bottom-left box definitely correct? I had a workable idea for what they mean, but it just didn't work. Seems too good a fit to not be related.

Comment: @pmacfarlane If you were refering to what is written in the answer below, then yes. I just  chose the first and last letter of rot13(gur svefg anzrf)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Seems there are slightly different versions of that rot13(yvfg bs ncbfgyrf) available, and I used the "wrong" one.

Comment: The image is severely disfigured on my phone in dark mode.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Each picture on the left has

> something 'missing' (see title)

> 1. These are the basic operators: plus, divide, subtract... multiply (TIMES) is missing.

> 2. The rainbow has only 6 segments, so one is missing. Violet is there and the others are equidistant, so RED must be missing.

> 3. These are the starting letters of the months of the year. M for MAY is missing.

> 4. These are the first and last letters of the names of the [12 apostles as listed in the book of Acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostles_in_the_New_Testament): James, John, Matthew, Andrew, James (2nd), Judas, Simon, Bartholomew, Philip, Thomas, Judas (2nd)... Missing is PETER.

> TIMES, RED, MAY, and PETER all hint at [famous city squares](https://www.touropia.com/city-squares-around-the-world/). (Each picture is also in a square, another clue).
>  Times Square is in the US, so #1 has a US flag.
>  The Red Square is in Russia, so #2 has a Russian flag.
>  Plaza de Mayo, or "May Square" in english, is in Argentina, so #3 has a flag of Argentina.

> Finally, Saint Peter's Square is in Vatican City, so the missing flag is:
>  [image: Vatican flag]

Comment: Great job! And ofc they're all inside rot13(fdnherf) too.

Comment: Ah, well-spotted